# instanceof in case of Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The first question I was asked in the interview, and to be honest I saw myself really confused and shown the door,

Consider the snippets:

***Case a:***

```
    var sayHello = new Function("alert('Hello there');");
    alert(sayHello instanceof Function);            // true 
    alert(sayHello instanceof Object);              // true, since every 
                                                    // object inherits from Object
```

***Case b:***

```
    var myFunction = function(){

    }

    var ins = new myFunction();              
    alert(ins instanceof myFunction);        // ofcourse, true
    alert(myFunction instanceof Function);   // true

    alert(ins instanceof Function);          // false, Why is this not true?
```

As per my understanding, ***Function*** must be in the ***prototypical chain*** of ***ins***?

```
ins <-- myFunction <-- Function <-- Object
```

Comment: Well, `ins` is not even a function

Comment: `ins` is an object, not a function, you can't call `ins()` here :)

Comment: @Wouter : But at that end, every function must inherit from Object.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: every function inherits from Object, true, but not every object is a function. In this case, it isn't. `myFunction` is a constructor function, calling `new` on it creates a new object that is not a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to misinterpret the `new` here in Javascript.

The

```
new myFunction()
```

doesn't create a new instance of the function. Rather it creates a new object which inherits from `myFunction.prototype` and calls `myFunction`, passing the object as `this` to the function.

Thus, you haven't really created a new instance of the function, your `ins` is not a function. You can easily verify it by trying to pretend it is:

```
var myFunction = function(){

}

var ins = new myFunction(); 

ins(); <-- error, ins is not a function
```

Since it is not a function, why would you expect the `Function` to be in its prototype chain?

Comment: This provided me with sense of relief.

Answer (score 3):

So, you have it close, but not quite. The prototypal chain is actually as follows:

```
ins <-- myFunction.prototype <-- Object
```

As you can see, the ins object inherits from the particular function prototype, and not from Function directly.

So, in essence ins is not an instance of a myFunction, so much as an instance of `myFunction.prototype`.

This can be more clearly be shown, by the fact that when you add functions to `myFunction.prototype`, they are attached to the instance of the object once it has been created.

For a great source of information on exactly what is happening, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new This explains the behaviour fully.

Comment: @major-major: I disagree with the line that "So, ins is not an instance of a myFunction". It clearly is.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari I'm simply trying to point out that `myFunction.prototype` is what ends in the prototype chain, and not `myFunction` directly

Answer (score 1):

`ins` is not `instanceof Function` because you declare it like an instance (`new myFunction`). So, it's an `instance` of myFunction.

Just reference `myFunction`:

```js
var myFunction = function(){};
var res = document.querySelector('#result');
var ins = myFunction;              
res.textContent = ['ins instanceof myFunction: ',ins instanceof myFunction,
                   '\nmyFunction instanceof Function: ', myFunction instanceof Function,
                   '\nins instanceof Function: ', ins instanceof Function].join('');
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trap you are falling into here is that you are assuming that the instanceof operator is transitive. You write

```
ins <-- myFunction <-- Function <-- Object
```

and conclude that it also holds that

```
ins <-- Function
```

It happens to be true that

```
myFunction <-- Object
```

but this is not due to a transitive instanceof.

In fact, the rule for instanceof is that if `a instanceof b` and `b.prototype instanceof c` it follows that `a instanceof c` but it is not required that `b instanceof c`. Look at this example:

```
function func() {}
function superFunc() {}
func.prototype = new superFunc();

var x = new func();
```

Now, `x` is an instance of `func` and `superFunc`, but `func` is not an instanceof `superFunc`. In other languages you would rather say that `func` is a **subclass** of `superFunc`.